# PHP Variable to Wordpress shop page

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess, variables

I have a link:

```
http://www.ignitionmarketing.co.za/products_promoDC.php?Product_Category=Corporate+Gifts
```

I would like it to be:

```
http://www.ignitionmarketing.co.za/product-category/corporate-gifts/
```

Also I have tried the normal way of:

```
Redirect 301 /products_promoDC.php?Product_Category=Corporate+Gifts http://www.ignitionmarketing.co.za/product-category/corporate-gifts/
```

But it still stays on a 404 page.

Could someone please help me?

Added Note:

I have a couple of other links that need to be redirected like:

```
/products_promoDC.php?Product_Category=Corporate+Clothing

/products_promoDC.php?Product_Category=Corporate+Clothing&Product_Subcategory=Shirts
```

The new WordPress shop does have the same categories as well.

Comment: I have made some progress

I have redirected the:
http://www.ignitionmarketing.co.za/products_promoDC.php?Product_Category=Corporate+Gifts

TO:

Comment: I have made some progress

I have redirected the:
http://www.ignitionmarketing.co.za/products_promoDC.php?Product_Category=Corporate+Gifts

TO: http://www.ignitionmarketing.co.za/shop/?Product_Category=Corporate+Clothing

All I need to dow now is to pass the parameters (?Product_Category=Corporate+Clothing) through the page or rewrite the url to /corporate-clothing/

Comment: I have found a way!

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Product_Category=([^&]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule products_promoDC\.php product-category/%1/? [L,R=301]

Now I just need to rewrite (Corporate+Clothing) to corporate-clothing..... any suggestons

Answer (score 0):

Just a better explanation to the solution. Maybe you come across a similar issue in the future.

I redirected my "products_promoDC.php" to /product-category/ so the Variable/Parameter is then only loaded behind (/product-category/Corporate+Clothing/) this still gave me a 404 error because of the plus (+) within the URL. I simply then wrote a RewriteRule to convert the pluses (+) to dashes!

Much easier than to do a RewriteMatch which could cause problems with the Subcategories.

```
RewriteRule "^([^+]*)\++([^+]*\+.*)$" /$1-$2 [N]
RewriteRule "^([^+]*)\++([^+]*)$" /$1-$2 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Product_Category=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Product_Subcategory=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule products_promoDC\.php product-category/%1/? [L,R=301]
```

I added a second line for my subcategories to load as well!

Working perfectly:
http://www.ignitionmarketing.co.za/products_promoDC.php?Product_Category=Corporate+Gifts